# What is the "Name=value" in [MyAttribute(Name=value)]

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes

I don't know what phrasing to use to google this.

Consider this attribute:

```
 [MyAttribute(MyOption=true,OtherOption=false)]
```

What is the `Name=value` part? And how can I implement it in my own custom attributes?

Comment: Display(Name="Value")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this by declaring public instance (*non-static*) properties or fields:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string TestValue { get; set; }
}

[My(TestValue = "Hello World!")]
public class MyClass{}
```

So it works almost like the object initializer syntax, but with `()` instead of `{}`.

---

If you provide a constructor with parameters for your attribute, you have to pass the parameters first:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string TestValue { get; set; }

    public MyAttribute(int arg)
    {}
}

[My(42, TestValue = "Hello World!")]
public class MyClass{}
```

Comment: Great thanks. How can that be used then with `[MyAttribute("foo",TestValue = "Hello World!"]`?

Comment: Typo: There's a `)` missing after `"Hello World!"`in both usages of `MyAttribute`.

Answer (score 3):

C# Specification [17.2 Attribute specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(v=vs.71).aspx):

> An attribute consists of an attribute-name and an optional list of
>   *positional* and *named arguments*. The positional arguments (if any)
>   precede the named arguments. A positional argument consists of an
>   attribute-argument-expression; a named argument consists of a name,
>   followed by an equal sign, followed by an
>   attribute-argument-expression, which, together, are constrained by the
>   same rules as simple assignment. The order of named arguments is not
>   significant.

So here

```
[MyAttribute(MyOption=true,OtherOption=false)]
```

you have two **named arguments**. What is named argument? Again, C# Specification [17.3.1 Compilation of an attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664618(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Name must identify a non-static read-write public field or property on
>   T (attribute type). If T has no such field or property, then a compile-time error
>   occurs.

Pretty clear, I believe. Those names either non-static public properties (most likely) with getter and setter or non-static public fields declared in `MyAttribute` class:

```
 public class MyAttribute : Attribute
 {
     public bool MyOption { get; set; }
     public bool OtherOption { get; set; }
 }
```

If you need more named arguments - add another non-static public read-write property or non-static public field with name you want to use.

```
 public class MyAttribute : Attribute
 {
     public bool MyOption { get; set; }
     public bool OtherOption { get; set; }
     public int Answer { get; set; }
     // public int Answer;  <- another option
 }
```

Usage (order does not matter):

```
 [MyAttribute(MyOption=true, Answer=42, OtherOption=false)]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's specifying a property when creating an instance of the attribute.

Attributes can have constructor parameters and properties - this one is setting a property. Note that you can mix positional constructor arguments, named constructor arguments and properties, as shown in the sample below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class DemoAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Ctor1 { get; set; }
    public string Ctor2 { get; set; }
    public string Ctor3 { get; set; }

    public DemoAttribute(string ctor1,
                         string ctor2 = "default2", 
                         string ctor3 = "default3")
    {
        Ctor1 = ctor1;
        Ctor2 = ctor2;
        Ctor3 = ctor3;
    }
}

[Demo("x", ctor3: "y", Property = "z")]
public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var attr = (DemoAttribute) typeof(Test).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DemoAttribute)).First();
        Console.WriteLine($"Property: {attr.Property}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Ctor1: {attr.Ctor1}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Ctor2: {attr.Ctor2}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Ctor3: {attr.Ctor3}");
    }
}
```

Note the difference between `:` for a named constructor argument, and `=` for a property assignment.

The output of this code is

```
Property: z
Ctor1: x
Ctor2: default2
Ctor3: y
```

It's unfortunate that the C# specification calls both named constructor arguments and properties "named arguments" in this case :(

Answer (score 1):

This is called as Named parameter of an Attribute. Actually the property of an attribute class. More info available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx